# How to display fields in new line in same textBox?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, telerik, telerik-reporting

I am using Silverlight4 and Telerik Reporting Q3 2011. I am trying to Generate Reports of all Outlets.
I used Table to display its fields. And I want to Display Full Address in same cell.
How could I?

I Used following Experession to display Full Address in same cell.

```
 = Fields.AddressLine1
     + ", " + Fields.AddressLine2
     + ", " + Fields.Suburb
     + ", " + Fields.City
     + ", " + Fields.State
     + ", " + Fields.Country
```

I want do display this in same cell but want output like below..

```
 =====================
       Address
 =====================
  15A,
  xxxx xxxRoad,
  xxxxxx,
  xxxxxxxx
 ====================
```

But I m getting this

```
 =====================
       Address
 =====================
  15A, xxxx xxxRoad, xxxxxx, xxxxxxxx
 =====================
```

How do I get Output Which I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Got it.....

I made the Function NewLineFeeds() in this function I used Replace() Method to replace the specific string to newLine(\n) .

```
 public static string NewLineFeeds(string text)
    {
        string result = text.Replace(", ", "\n");
        result = result.Replace(", ", "\n");
        result = result.Replace(", ", "\n");
        return result;
    }
```

and my Expression is

```
 =NewLineFeeds(Fields.AddressLine1 
 + ", " + Fields.AddressLine2 
 + ", " + Fields.Suburb 
 + ", " + Fields.City 
 + ", " + Fields.State 
 + ", " + Fields.Country)
```

This call the Function NewLineFeeds() and replace ", " to \n (new Line).
Add this will work Fine..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `\n` or `\r\n` in your strings wherever you want to do line breaks?

Comment: I tried this but doesnt work I also tried Environment.NewLine but it also not working

Comment: when using \n or \r it shows me error that '\r \n\' not defined in current context

Comment: you DO place \r\n between after the comma, between the dubble quotes? Environment.Newline should do the trick (outside the quotes that is), weird it doesn't.  

so _Fields.AddressLine1
     + ", \r\n" + Fields.AddressLine2_ or _Fields.AddressLine1
     + ", " + Environment.Newline + Fields.AddressLine2_

Comment: Maybe you must check a MultiLine property? In Visual Studio, for example, you need to do that for textboxes

Comment: If I use \r\n in between inverted comma it will display \r\n as a text.

Answer (score 0):

Use Environment.NewLine for getting into new line, see below

```
=Fields.AddressLine1 + ", " 
+ Environment.NewLine + Fields.AddressLine2 + ", " 
+ Environment.NewLine + Fields.Suburb + ", " 
+ Environment.NewLine + Fields.City + ", " 
+ Environment.NewLine + Fields.State + ", " 
+ Environment.NewLine + Fields.Country;
```

EDIT

Refer to the link [how to insert a newline in Textblock in silverlight](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/67564.aspx)

Comment: It shows me error "Expression contains object 'Environment' that is not defined in current Context".

Comment: Use the namespace "using System" at the top.

Comment: where you have put the namespace, put the using System at the namespace declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Use complete name `System.Environment.NewLine` and it will work. 
I just confirmed it in my report.